# A-frame.js a-sky occasionally using cube geometry instead of sphere on successive embedded loads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aframe

In a current project that loads successive a-frame scenes (using vue-router, on different routes) a-sky will sometimes appear with a cube instead of sphere geometry.

The pano image texture will be shown in entirety on each of the cube faces, and the console will log an warning about "Unknown property `radius` for component/system `geometry`," presumably because it cannot apply the radius attribute I'm setting on sky.

(This is with current A-frame master pulled from Github Dec 1, 2018 commit.)

Comment: FWIW, as a quick fix I was able to use a workaround as indicated by Diego Marcus [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3428#issuecomment-372076295) and simply use a generic entity instead of a-sky.

Comment: Thanks, maybe a bug.